# Javascript RegEx how to make:"word1—word2" to"word1 — word2"

Tags: javascript, regex

I've got a sentence that contains dashes without whitespace around them.  I want to insert spaces, but only if there is none (I don't want to double spaces).

```
"word1—word2" to "word1 — word2"
```

...but not:

```
"word1 — word2" to "word1  —  word2"
```

I guess I could dot this with:

```
text.replace(/—/g, " — ").replace(/  —  /g, " — ");
```

...but I wonder if there is a simpler way to achieve the goal.

Answer (score 2):

```
text.replace(/([^ ])-([^ ])/g, "$1 - $2");
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you explain what does this mean [^ ]? could I use [\S]?

Comment: `[^ ]` just means "any character that is not a space". Since that's what you asked for, I just put that in. `\S` could probably also work.

Answer (score 1):

The escape code `\b` is a zero-width assertion for "word boundary". By matching for `\b—\b`, you will only match the dash if it has a "word" character on each side.

`text.replace(/\b—\b/g, " — ");`

Because the assertion is zero-width, you don't need to include groups, which simplifies your regex.

Comment: +1, but note that the search character is an *[em dash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash#Em_dash)* and not a hyphen.  I've edited your answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

```
text.replace(/(^|[^ ])-([^ ]|$)/g, "$1 - $2");
```

should do it.

`....replace(/  —  /g, " — ")` will not work since it will double spaces when there is only space on one side of the dash as in `"foo- bar"`.

Answer (score 0):

```
text = text.replace(/\s*—\s*/g, " — ");
```

Given an already well-formed string it will replace one space with one space, but that doesn't hurt anything.  If there's no whitespace, too much, or the wrong kind, it will be normalized to one space.